# jframe actionperformed jframe

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jbutton

I currently have a button that, when clicked, performs a method that creates a jframe with a panel that loads multiple images. If this button is clicked multiple times, the images keep adding onto the prexisting images loaded onto the jframe. What code should I use so that if the button is clicked after the jframe and elements have been loaded, after clicking once, nothing else will be added.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
  button.setEnabled(false);

  // the other code that creates imgFrame

  imgFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      @Override public void windowClosing(WindowEvent evt) {
          button.setEnabled(true);
      }});

  imgFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: You just have to remember to re-enable it when the other JFrame closes.

Comment: @jschoen Yes, you do. I added a way to do that to the example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. don't create lots of [JFrames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) on the runtime, because these Object never gone from `Used JVM Memory` untill current `JVM` instance exist
2. you have look at [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) that very confortly to solve your issues with multiple of views (in this case in one `JFrame`)
3. put Images as [Icon/ImageIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) to the [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)

Comment: It just creates one jframe and with every button click adds the pics to the one jframe

Comment: getting the images as jlabels isn't the issue here

Comment: I'm talking here about wrong experiences, blank aisles and solutions how to do ..., everything is up to you

Comment: random bullets, none related to the question (afaics)

Answer (score 0):

Disable the button when frame show up, and when the frame close, enable the button.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

    final JButton finalButton = button;
    button.setEnabled(false);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame()
    {
        protected void processWindowEvent(WindowEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING)
            {
                finalButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
            super.processWindowEvent(e);
        }
    };
    frame.setVisible(true);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a boolean that is false when the program starts, and then when the button is clicked, it tests if the boolean is false. If it is false, then create the stuff that you want, and then make it true. If it is true, do nothing, or alert the user not to click the button more that once, or something of that matter

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean isAlreadyCreated = false;

yourButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    if(!isAlreadyCreated)
    {
        //CREATE YOUR NEW FRAME
        isAlreadyCreated = true;
    }
});
```